# Passing data from HTML form through Flask to an API

Tags: python, flask

So I'm currently making an application in Python that would show live departures and then show a countdown when there are 0 minutes to departure. What my issue is that I don't want to edit the code to change stops, I want to just be able to input the route_type and stop from the html formand then pass that via Flask to the API.

The API is the [PTV Timetable API](https://timetableapi.ptv.vic.gov.au/swagger/ui/index) that includes real time departures.
The API has a Swagger page so I know what to insert.

So what I've done is added the authentication code and then added the forms from bootstrap into the HTML file. I've tried googling the problem but I don't really know how the HTML forms can talk to flask so it can get added to the API.
Thanks

**Python Code**

```
def getUrl(request):
DevId = <ID>
apikey = <KEY>
request = request + ('&amp;') if ('?' in request) else '?')
raw = 'request' +'DevId={0}'.format(DevId)
hashkey = hmac.new(key, raw, sha1)
signature = hashkey.hexdigest()
return ''https://timetableapi.ptv.vic.gov.au'+raw+'&amp;signature={1}'.format(devId, signature)

from_zone = tz.gettz('UTC')
to_zone = tz.gettz ('Australia/Melbourne')

#get next departures
url = getUrl('/v3/departures/route_type/{route_type}/stop/{stop_id}')


@app.route('/')
@app.route('home')
    def home():
        return flask.render_template('home.html')
```

**HTML Code**

```
<body>
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="station-id-input">Station ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Station ID">
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inline-train" value="route_type0">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inline-train">Train</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inline-tram" value="route_type1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inline-train">Tram</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inline-bus" value="route_type2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inline-train">Bus</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inline-vline" value="route_type3">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inline-train">V/Line</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inline-nightbus" value="route_type4" disabled>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inline-train"Night Bus (Not Implemented)</label>
      </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a good and well documented way to communicate with `flask` from `html` is via [flask wtforms](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). It helps you essentially to validate your forms in the html and to secure the `POST` requests from the frontend usually via a CSRF token.

From the documentation you have a minimal example that could be a good starting point for you:

```py
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('name', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

#### HTML

PS: The curling brackets are from [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/), a templating language for python.

```html
<form method="POST" action="/">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.name.label }} {{ form.name(size=20) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

#### Validating

```py
@app.route('/submit', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def submit():
    form = MyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect('/success')
    return render_template('submit.html', form=form)
```

It is fairly straightforward, you create a form, pass it to the frontend together in the routing and then when the user submits it it tries to validate it.

---

With all that said, if all you want is to simply send a form data and process that in flask, all you really need to do is create / accept POST requests in your endpoint:

```py
@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@app.route('home')
    def home():
        if request.method == 'POST':
           form = request.form
           value1 = form['value1']
           # do something with the values from the form.
        return flask.render_template('home.html')
```

I would not recommend due to validation / security concerns, but it could be a starting point if you are new to flask.